# Is possible to change the AssemblyCopyright attribute of an exe?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, exe, .net-assembly

I would like to know if its possible to change the attribute above of an exe without having their source code.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright Example")]
```

In order that when this exe calls the following code, the modified attribute comes.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute), false)[0];
```

I tried ResourceHacker, unfortunately it only changes the copyright on right click > properties > details. If I decompile the .exe again, I will get the old copyright.

I also tried to compile the code after to decompile it, but I had no success.

The company changed their name but they didn't keep the source code of this legacy product version. And now I have to change it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem by doing this:

1. Using [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), decompile the assembly.

   > ildasm MyFile.exe /output:MyFile.il
2. Open the extracted file "MyFile.il" with a text editor.
3. You will see something like this:

   > .custom instance void
   >   [mscorlib]System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute::.ctor(string) =
   >
   > ( 01 00 2C 43 6F 70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20 C2 A9 20   // ..,Copyright ..
   >
   > 45 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 00 00 )                      // Example
4. The hex code is your copyright string, you may change it, but take care about this notes:

   -The first two pairs 01 and 00 indicates the start of the string.

   -The last two pairs 00 and 00 indicates the end of the string.

   -You must NOT change the length of the hex code (I don't know why.. an exception is thrown when you are going to read it. I added empty spaces (20) in the end of the hex code to match the length).
5. Now you just have to compile it again with [ilasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(v=vs.110).aspx).

   > ilasm /resource=MyFile.res /exe /output=MyFile.exe MyFile.il

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution to consider: You can check the solution that they propose here: [AssemblyCopyrightAttribute Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycopyrightattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

The alternative solution is that you could use a tool named .NET Reflector ([Redgate .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)) to competely decompile the entire code, and then build it up again in a new Visual Studio project where you assign the Copyright attribute on your own.

In both solutions please make sure you are OK on the legal perspective, so that you do not break the law.

Comment: As I said, I tried to decompile the exe, but it was impossible to compile it again. About the other option, it doesn't describes how to modify an existing assembly, just creates a new assembly. Thank you!